# Why this SQL Server query can't work when I put it into a C# method?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have the following problem trying to insert the following SQL server query into a C# method:

```
select *
from   VulnerabilityReference
where  Title = 'Message'
and    convert(nvarchar(MAX), Description2) = N'http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/1201040152.5924.44.camel@laptop'
```

As you can see the **Description2** field is casted

In Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio the previous query work well and give me the following output:

```
Id         Title       Description2

52794      Message     http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/1201040152.5924.44.camel@laptop
55340      Message     http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/1201040152.5924.44.camel@laptop
55341      Message     http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/1201040152.5924.44.camel@laptop
55342      Message     http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/1201040152.5924.44.camel@laptop
```

Now I creat the following **exist()** method in C#

```
    public long existReference(DataModel.Vulnerability.Reference reference)
    {
        long id = -1;
        _strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VulnerabilityReference"
                + " WHERE Title = @REFERENCETITLE and convert(nvarchar(MAX), Description2) = N'@DESCRIPTION2' ";

        System.Data.Common.DbCommand command;
        command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        _addParameter(command, "@REFERENCETITLE", reference.Title);
        _addParameter(command, "@DESCRIPTION2", reference.Description2);

        command.CommandText = _strSQL;

        _dt = _fillDataTable(command);

        if (_dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        id = _dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("Id");
        return id;
    }
```

The two field of the reference object contains the same values of the previous example but it don't work fine and found 0 records for this query.

Why? What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Tnx

Comment: Others have already answered your question but why do you need to cast `description2` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`? It seems unnecessary

Comment: @OGHaza because the field in the table is `NTEXT` which is invalid in an equality. OP hasn't mentioned it, but that was the basis of an earlier question of theirs today.

Comment: Ah, I see - I've never worked with TEXT types - thanks @Steve

Comment: @OGHaza Keep it that way - they're being deprecated and they're a bit of a nuisance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query should look like

```
 _strSQL = "SELECT * FROM VulnerabilityReference"
            + " WHERE Title = @REFERENCETITLE and convert(nvarchar(MAX), Description2) = @DESCRIPTION2 ";
```

Answer (score 4):

`N'@DESCRIPTION2'` is looking for the **literal** text `@DESCRIPTION2` (not the value of the parameter by that name). If you want the parameter value, just use `@DESCRIPTION2`:

```
WHERE ...(blah)... = @DESCRIPTION2
```

Answer (score 4):

Drop all things around variables that tell the parser what type of variable it is. That's already known:

```
N'@DESCRIPTION2'
```

in your statement needs to be

```
@DESCRIPTION2
```